# Spring Native fails to Execute org.graalvm.buildtools

Tags: spring-boot, spring-native

I followed the instructions on [Getting Started Native Build Tools](https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-native-build-tools)
in order to create a standalone executable using [Spring Native](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-native).

When I execute the package goal

```
mvn -Pnative -DskipTests package
```

I get the following error (I also get a lot of `Could not register` warnings, which should be okay according to the documentation)

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.image.NativeImageViaCC.handleLinkerFailure(NativeImageViaCC.java:513)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.image.NativeImageViaCC.write(NativeImageViaCC.java:460)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:710)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$run$2(NativeImageGenerator.java:495)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1407)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1
...
Failed to execute goal org.graalvm.buildtools:native-maven-plugin:0.9.0:build
```

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt install zlib1g-dev
```

After that I was successfully able to start the application